# Meaning of "dans ce monde de taches?"

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

This is from MC Solaar's RMI, a song about injustices done to the underprivileged:

> Le monstre aux yeux verts, synonyme de la jalousie
>   Taxe l'eau du Sahel juste pour remplir son jacuzzi
>   Mais c'est comme ça que ça fonctionne...
>    ...dans ce monde de taches ?

Dans ce monde de taches translates directly to "In this world of spots/smudges?"

I understand it's a rhetorical question meaning something like "in this terrible world?" or something. Do smudges (taches) refer to bad people?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Tache*** is slang for a loser (a dud), not necessarily a bad or dishonest person but a derogatory term nonetheless. It's very modern slang, I have a 20th c. slang dictionary and it isn't in it.

I don't know for sure where it comes from. Most likely from the  colloquial phrase *faire tache* which means "to stand out in a conspicuous or ridiculous  way".

*Un monde de taches* → a world of losers.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, "une tache" is primarily a spot, a smudge.

By extension, it is a slang word to designate metaphorically someone who "does not fit correctly" : incompetent, inept.

It is used in France since the 90's approximatively.